# Excluding posts from WordPress loop when the argument is an array

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress, I have the below code that renders posts based on custom meta data I have applied to a post. Basically, if the user ticks a box in the post the sponsor is either lead sponsor or silver sponsor (custom post called a sponsor) it will add the meta data '_url_premium' or '_silver_sponsor_silver' depending on the sponsor type.

I then render those posts (i.e. sponsors) as below:

```
<?php  $args = array(
                    'post_type'=>'sponsor',
                    'posts_per_page'=>-1);

        query_posts($args);

        if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' );
            $image_w = $image[1];
            $image_h = $image[2];
            $image = $image[0];
            $postmeta = get_post_custom();

            if( has_post_thumbnail()  && !empty($postmeta['_url_premium'][0]) ) : ?>

                <div class="sponsorbox2 grid-parent">
                    <h3 class="sidetitle grid-100">Lead Sponsor</h3>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="grid-50 prefix-50 mobile-grid-100"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" ></a>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <?php $leadsponsor = $post->ID; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                <div class="sponsorbox2 grid-parent">
                    <h3 class="sidetitle grid-100">Silver Sponsors</h3>

    <?php $args = array(
                    'post_type'=>'sponsor',
                    'posts_per_page'=>-1);

        query_posts($args);

        if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' );
            $image_w = $image[1];
            $image_h = $image[2];
            $image = $image[0];
            $postmeta = get_post_custom();

            if( has_post_thumbnail()  && !empty($postmeta['_silver_sponsor_silver'][0]) ) : ?>


                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="grid-50 prefix-50 mobile-grid-100"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" ></a>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <?php $silversponsor = $post->ID; ?>
```

I then render all other posts (i.e. sponsors) that do not contain the meta data with:

```
        <div class="sponsorbox grid-parent">

            <?php if(!empty($leadsponsor) && !empty($silversponsor)) : ?>

                <h3 class="sidetitle grid-100">Our other Sponsors</h3>

            <?php else : ?>

                <h3 class="sidetitle grid-100">Our Sponsors</h3>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <!-- logos should be grid-30 and mobile-grid-25 -->
            <?php  $args = array(
                            'post_type'=>'sponsor',
                            'posts_per_page'=>-1 );

                    query_posts($args);

                    if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' );
                        $image_w = $image[1];
                        $image_h = $image[2];
                        $image = $image[0];


                        $proportion = ($image_w / $image_h);
            ?>

            <?php if( has_post_thumbnail()  && $post->ID != $leadsponsor && $post->ID !=$silversponsor ) : ?>

                <?php if( $proportion > 1.2 ) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="grid-50 mobile-grid-50"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" ></a>
                <?php else : ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="grid-25 mobile-grid-25"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" ></a>
                <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This works well as the lead sponsor renders by itself and it de-duplicated from the list of normal sponsors further down. This works well too for the silver sponsors as they are listed in their section and then de-duplicate from the list of normal sponsors further down.

The problem has come when I add a second silver sponsor. It renders the second silver sponsor just fine but is not de-duplicating the second silver sponsor from the list of normal sponsors further below.

My thoughts are that since there are two silver sponsors, it is not picking up the second silver sponsor (i.e. post) for some reason (perhaps the same meta data) but I am not sure. Any assistance or direction would be appreciated.

Happy to send the live site in a PM if it will help (don't want to list the URL here for indexing...).

Thanks,

IcedQuick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing using the `meta_query` argument in your query `$args`. For example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sponsor',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_url_premium',
            'value' => array( 3, 4 ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        )
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        // Do something here.
    }

} else {
    // No posts match.
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

In this example, all posts of type `sponsor` that have a meta key of `_url_premium` and a meta value of either `3` or `4` will be returned.

**Note:** If the meta values you need to use are in post meta, then you can use a function such as `get_post_meta()` to retrieve those values.

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Comment: Thanks for this. But can you please explain - this will ensure that all posts of the type sponsor and with the meta key of _url_premium are returned - but I am doing that already. I am wanting to exclude _url_premium and _silver_sponsor_silver from the post generation

Comment: I was showing you an approach which will give you greater control over what is retuned by your query. If you take a look at the query `$args` I've used, you'll see how you can use the `meta_query` argument to return the exact posts you need.